# state level of significance at beginning?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am doing hypothesis testing at the moment and I read somewhere a few weeks ago that it is important to state the level of significance at the beginning. But I can't really recall the reason.  I have a feeling it's that it prevents bias by the researcher because he/she can change the level of alpha with the way they want the outcome to be. Is this correct?

Comment: That is of course if we take seriously the idea of picking an arbitrary $p$-value cutoff and then making a binary decision based on that threshold.  The strength of the evidence doesn't depend on such a choice, so personally I think the approach is problematic even when done "properly."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's essentially the issue.

Imagine you could choose your significance level after you saw the p-value. Then you could always get a significant result by choosing your significance level to be slightly larger than your observed p-value.

You'd only fail to reject when you had a p-value bigger than the very largest significance level you'd have the chutzpah to try on.

This means that when you did get a p-value of say 0.04 and you reject at the 5% level, that doesn't imply that when H0 is true you will make the correct decision 95% of the time ... you'll just change what significance level you claimed.

If you're tempted to do something like that, better to simply leave $\alpha$ out of it and just state your p-value, and let people apply their own significance level.

This sort of trick is perhaps the simplest (though often most obvious) of a large collection of potential "p-hacking" or data dredging tricks.